# Highlighting a cell in one column when matching value found anywhere in a second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Column B is where data is going to be entered.
Column I has a list of data that is predefined.

I want column I's data to be highlighted when the data is found anywhere in column B. Example:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F   G    H    I    J
---------------------------------------------
     3                                 1
     2                                 2
     7                                 3
```

So the cells in column I containing `2` and `3`  would be highlighted because found in Column B at some point.

Comment: Use CF with a formula - `COUNTIF()` should work

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting ColumnI, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting - New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, *Format values where this formula is true:*

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,I1)>0
```

choose your formatting, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formating with

```
 =isna(match($i1,$b$1:$b$3,0))
```

as the condition for cells that don't match  (the zero is important as it means exact matches only)

... but

```
 =countif($b$1:$b$3,$i1)=0
```

will do the same thing, while

```
=countif($b$1:$b$3,$i1)>0
```

is a condition for matches